# Drawing a graph with indexedDB values using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I'm trying to use an array from my **indexedDB**, to plot a graph on **Chart.js** for my web application. I've attached the code from my javascript file where the array is obtained.
The array looks like this `Objarr = ["34", "89"]` and the numbers are added to the array when the user inputs these.
But I'm not able to say data: Objarr in my javascript code for the chart? Please, may you help me?

Javascript Code:

```
var chart = document.getElementById('lineChart').getContext('2d');
var lineChart = new Chart(chart, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: " Peak flow values",
    fill: false,
    data: Objarr,
  }
]
```

Comment: Is this your full code? It looks like it's missing some braces and parens.

Comment: Hi Milo, @MiloP, yes it is and yes there is supposed to be a  } }); at the end :) I have more code but it's too long to send it here, and it's javascript code to actually obtain the array Objarr from user input.